# When I enter sculpting mode I can not find m

Tags: import, file-format, .fbx

I import .fbx file in this scenes,the other model is all right, just "H" I can not find in sculpting mode.

I try to rotate\move\scale,but the "H" is still show in the sculpting

[image: I import .fbx]

[image: No model visible]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: press alt+h in sculpt mode